# Configuring vimwiki in neovim

Tags: neovim, lua, plugin-vimwiki, lazyvim

I am struggling with the basic configuration for vimwiki in neovim. I cannot get it to use my configuration. For import I am using [lazy.nvim](https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim). This is the concerning lazy-section:

```
    {"vimwiki/vimwiki", 
    config = function() 
        vim.g.vimwiki_list = {
            {
            path = '~/docs/vimwiki',
            syntax = 'default',
            ext = '.wiki',
            },
        }
    end,
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading the docs for [lazy.nvim](https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim) I found out that you should use `init()` instead of `config()`.

```
        {"vimwiki/vimwiki", 
    init = function() 
        vim.g.vimwiki_list = {
            {
            path = '~/docs/vimwiki',
            syntax = 'default',
            ext = '.wiki',
            },
        }
    end,
    },
```

This is because vimwiki needs to know the `vimwiki_list` **before loading**, to know where to find all wikis. `init()` loads always and `config()` just loads when the plugin loads.